# Linux won't boot, no grub rescue

Tags: linux, boot, grub

I have a dual boot Windows 10 / Linux Mint. But now maybe after a Windows Update when I try to boot Linux I have a black screen with a blinking cursor. I had a similar issue recently but I manage to recover everything as grub rescue showed up. But not this time. When I press shift I have "GRUB" that shows up on the screen but I can't do anything. I went through a lot of research and I can't find anything. What can I do ?

Comment: You should try plugging a live Ubuntu USB stick and reinstall/reconfigure your bootloader.

Comment: Can you clarify the part from "try to boot Linux" to "black screen with a blinking cursor", starting with turning on the power?  It isn't clear how much, if any, of the boot process takes place after you turn on the power, or what you have access to for trying to boot Linux.  For example, this description could apply to getting no boot provision at all, to getting the GRUB menu but that leads directly to a black screen, to having the GRUB menu and starting the Linux boot but it never reaches loading the desktop.

Comment: When I turn on the power, I have the screen that allows me te access the bios. Then I have the black screen and I'm stuck.
The thing is I messed up and installed Linux on Legacy while Windows is on UEFI.

Comment: No, you have a computer, on which you have installed Linux after Windows 10 was installed. Please look on the serial number plate and find the make and model of the computer, then click [edit] and amend your question with that useful information.